# C# Web API :Marking a class serializable makes me unable to use it as an incoming request object

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api, fluent-nhibernate, json.net

Using: MVC4, Newtonsoft.JSON, fluent nhibernate
everything else is standard

I may be going about this completely wrong, but I have the following Web API method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(SomeClass value)
{
    try
    {
        dh.commitWrite(value);
        var resp = Request.CreateResponse<int>(HttpStatusCode.Accepted,value.Id);
        return resp;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var resp = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable,ex);
            return resp;
    }
}
```

Fairly straightforward. The SomeClass class is this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [Serializable]
    [JsonProperty]
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public virtual string field1 { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<anotherClass> genericListHere { get; set; }

    public SomeClass()
    {
        genericListHere = new List<anotherClass>();
    }
};
```

Now for the strange bit: When I mark SomeClass as [Serializable], Post(SomeClass value) recognises that value is of type SomeClass, but all the fields/properties are blank or null. When I remove [Serializable], it goes through just fine.

My code for testing this is:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomeClassPOSTWithJSON()
{
  var json = "{\"field1\":\"someValue\"}";
  var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:47949/api/someClass/Post");
  httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
  httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

  using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
         streamWriter.Write(json);
         streamWriter.Flush();
         streamWriter.Close();

         var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
         using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

I mark the someClass class as [Serializable] because of how I perform deep copy operations on it.

Thanks for any help!

PS: 
- I've tried formatting the JSON string without escape sequences. This didn't work
- I've tried creating the object on the test side and then transforming it into JSON using Jsonconvert.SerializeObject. This didn't work either.
- If I pass an actual object using HTTPClient, it works fine, but this means I'll need to have copies of the object on the client. I'd rather avoid it if possible.

Comment: You might encounter this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092294/upgrade-of-newtonsoft-json-net-not-implicitly-serialising-protected-members

Comment: That worked! I am somehow unable to mark your answer as an answer though. I guess that's because it's an edit. Thanks very much!